# wipe user data after restart android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I'm using eclipse for programming android.
After each restart emulator I must use wipe user data and then work with that, otherwise emulator can run but does not react.

please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a simple shell script to wipe the emulator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
EMULATOR_NAME='Nexus_6P_API_23'
emulator -avd ${EMULATOR_NAME} -wipe-data
```